# End email to seed email adresses without subscriber key

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, api, soap-api

I am using marketing cloud APIs to create an email and a data extension to send email to. The subscriber key is user id from the application and we also have email id against each user id. I would like to send the email to some seed email addresses as well. The seed email address do not belong to app users and therefore do not have a user id. How can I send an email to these seed email address when I send email to users in data extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For subscribers who don’t have a subscriber key / user id, use their email addresses as their subscriber key, eg.

```
subscriber 1: 
email: test@email.com
subscriber key: 12345

subscriber 2:
email: test2@email.com
subscriber key: test2@email.com
```

Alternatively, if the system you are using for sending subscribers via API allows it, you could generate a guid to use as subscriber key / user id for users who don’t already have it.